# Can aragonOSx plugins be any kind of plugins or do they need to be only governance?

Tags: solidity, governance

Is it that you see plugins merely as "governance plugins" (i.e. used for various flavours of voting)? As opposed to apps which could extend the functionality of the app in various unforeseen ways?

Answer (score 0):

They can extend functionalities for the DAO in any unforeseen way the developer wants.

Governance plugins are one such type, but for example, we can also do financial plugins with integrations to other projects, coordination plugins based on token holders, etc.

You essentially use the permissions (both the ones already established in the protocol + the ones developers can custom build within their plugin) to grant or revoke access to addresses to execute actions. That's it - and based on that mental model, anything is possible.